# How to change name on BRP and whether I have to pay 1000£ fine (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom

I have a limited leave to remain BRP and don't hold a IRL. Am 19 and changed my surname to my mother's maiden name. How do I get a new BRP?  There is a form on the UK government website to send by post but there is also a online form you can do to get a new BRP.

Furthermore, my replacement Mauritian passport was issued October last year, the processing took a long time e.g. printing on newspaper and such and lock down made it go over the 3 months time span to update your info before I received it in the UK. Do I really have to pay a big fine?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have answered the first question of how to get a new BRP: there are two online forms, one to send by post, and another to file online. Decide which method you wish to use, and use it.

Comment: @Shinji Hirako The part of your question about lockdown, which began on 23 March in the UK, affecting update of your BRP after the issue of a passport last October (five months before the start of lockdown), is unclear. If you changed your name in Oct 2019, you should have submitted your request for a new BRP by say end of January latest, long before the Covid emergency got anywhere near lockdown.

Comment: It was issued (made) on the 23rd October without yet being approved. They told me I needed my fingerprints to be in the system however I was back in the UK. They just added the biometric system as well which made it annoying as my mum did her passport the year before without needing it. I went to a fingerprint booth in the UK and then sent it to them. They had a problem where their fingerprint machine didn't recognise my fingerprints and I had to do it and send a new copy again.They finally done it around  end of January but the passport needed to be processed and approved which didn't happen.

Comment: After the postal office was back open in Mauritius, I contacted them and they told me they have processed the passport and have stamped an approval date of last week Tuesday for it ready to be used. . Since am going to do the online form, it ask for the new passport details so I had to wait til I received it. Someone on Reddit told they don't just fine because of a delay, only if the person has e.g. convictions or shady events on their record and haven't given the info in the 3 month period. Thanks for helping both of you.

Comment: My mum told me things are very strict and slow there unless you bribe someone. The passport needed to be in the newspaper 2 times to make sure 'members of the public accepts it'. One needs to be approved by an attorney general and after no objection to the change be signed by that person again.